# GCM Cloud Connection Server - how to start using it?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to use GCM cloud connection server. So far I have read [GCM Cloud Connection Server](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html) and I'm confused. At top of page there is link to form.

My question is:

Do I need to fill it and wait for a response form Google saying that they enabled GCM CCS for my project, or can I start coding without filling the form?

If answer is that I need fill that form, are there any restrictions as to who can use it? Because I did fill it with sample data (confirmed by id of project from Google console) and got no answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start coding whenever you wish, but until Google whitelist your API Project ID (the one you should specify in the sign-up form), the new features (CCS and user notifications) won't work for you.

Comment: Do you know that when will it be released ? I guess it is trial right now.

Comment: @BarbarosAlp I don't know. C2DM was on trial for a long period of time (two years?) before they deprecated it and replaced it with GCM last year. CCS might be on trial for a long period too.